# Is there a way to do a double foreach, with or without tuple types?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Like, let's say you have two lists of similar number of objects. Is there a way to do a foreach using 1 variable from list1 and 1 variable from list 2 at the same time, with or without tuple types? (and not foreach in a foreach)

For example, we have list1 and list2. This would be what i'd imagine (not necesarily correct).

```
    foreach( var (x,y) from (list1, list2))
    {

    }
```

Comment: could you show an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) documentation.

The way this would be implemented is:

```cs
foreach ( var ( x, y ) in listA.Zip( listB, ( a, b ) => ( a, b ) ) ) {
    ...
}
```

Note that this is **not** a "2D" loop, it only goes through each value once.
If you want to make a "2D" loop, you will need to either use 2 loops or implement an extension method that uses 2 loops anyway.